# Android Jetpack Compose. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool

Tags: android, crashlytics, jetpack-compose

Firebase is informing crash with stack trace below for OS Versions Android 7 and lower. I can't figure out where is the problem. The project is almost 100% written in Jetpack Compose but has a couple of AndroidViews

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already in the pool!
       at android.util.Pools$SimplePool.release(Pools.java:112)
       at android.util.Pools$SynchronizedPool.release(Pools.java:161)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.recycle(AccessibilityEvent.java:1044)
       at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityManager.java:332)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7122)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:906)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendEvent(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1169)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendSemanticsPropertyChangeEvents$ui_release(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:2123)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.checkForSemanticsChanges(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1888)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.semanticsChangeChecker$lambda$32(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt:1764)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.$r8$lambda$XMXpDxOWXXw8oFvZkg91zLjynx0(AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat.android.kt)
       at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeViewAccessibilityDelegateCompat$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(D8$$SyntheticClass)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

Please give some hints if you familiar with this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced same issue.

On xiaomi with android version 7.0

Can be reproduced when adding visual transformation to OutlinedTextField. And by changing it **passwordVisible** value crash happens

```
visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) {
    VisualTransformation.None
} else {
    PasswordVisualTransformation(mask = '\u002A')
}
```

Still looking for solution

**UPDT** disabling semantics for **OutlineTextField** fixing that error. But that can't be a solution...

```
modifier = modifier.clearAndSetSemantics {  }
```

Comment: I have used separate EditTexts to fix this error

Comment: Anyone already created or found an issue in the issuetracker which we can follow?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but cannot reproduce it like you said when I click on the button that changes the value of my passwordVisible, any ideas?

Comment: I have seen this same issue in production on a Samsung Galaxy J5 device with Android 7.1, also when showing the password. I am not able to reproduce on simulator with Android 7.0 or 7.1. I found a probably related but not the same issue on the issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297732416

Comment: I'm using compose version 1.5.1 (compose compiler version 1.5.3) and this issue seems to be fixed. (I don't need to clear the semantics anymore). Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Still reproduce with compose 1.5.4 and compiler 1.5.3 on Android 7.1.2

Comment: Works fine on Android 13, but on Android 6.0.1 exhibits the error. Both using compose-bom:2024.01.00